# Laravel 4 - Require packages on Laravel install

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, composer-php, package

I looked around for an answer to this question, but couldn't find anything.

Just wondering, is there a way to tell Composer to require additional packages during a laravel 4 installation?

For example: 
If I want to always use the Entrust package in all my laravel projects, instead of having to require it every time I create a new laravel project, can I tell my Composer to also require the Entrust package when I run `composer create-project laravel/laravel --prefer-dist`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of such thing in Composer, but you can add `require` statement to the same command:

`composer create-project laravel/laravel --prefer-dist ./ && composer require zizaco/entrust`